# Image outside post content Wordpress Post

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I try to fix so that the images I upload in posts, are positioned outside of the post content width.

Actually I don't know if there is a solution for it, but I have seen several wordpress blogs having it.

**Here is a example of how I want it:** http://demo.themefuse.com/aesthetic/garance-dore-is-launching-a-podcast-in-partnership-with-the-outnet/

If you see the **first** image in the post, its wider than the post content.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a particularly a WP question, but it may affect finer details of the solution. The method in the example you provided uses left and right padding on non image areas. The default WP editor doesn't split up the areas into multiple div's like in the example, though.

You didn't provide your HTML, but, I would approach with something like...

```
.post-content {
    box-sizing: border-box; // so that padding is part of the box area.
}
.post-content > * { // select all elements within your content area, or specifically things like p, h1, h2, etc.
    display: block;
    padding: 0 150px; // you could use padding using px, vw, etc.
    width: 70%; // OR use width. compare this with to the image below
}
.post-content > img:first-of-type { // this might need to change to something to select the first image, or all images
    width: 100%; // unlike the other elements, the image goes full width
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```